# Pylibmc: ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_pylibmc)

Tags: python, memcached, python-module

```
>>> import pylibmc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylibmc.py", line 55, in <module>
    import _pylibmc
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_pylibmc)
```

Trying to import pylibmc, which tries to import _pylibmc.so

I'm using Mac OSX 10.5.6

Comment: How are you installing it, from source? What version of pylibmc are you using. What version of libmemcached are you using?

Comment: I installed it from source since easy_install didn't work.  Using v. 1 of pylibmc, and 0.38 of libmemcached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very odd. I (the developer of pylibmc) use Mac OS X 10.6.3 to develop pylibmc, and libmemcached 0.38 should be fine.

Try downloading the actual tarball and unpacking it, then:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install --with-libmemcached=/path/to/libmemcached-0.38
(lots of output)
$ python -m pylibmc -v
```

Comment: oops forgot to close this one, but yes, that's what I ended up doing.  Thanks for making pylibmc :)

Comment: @lericson

Hello! I am having sort of the same error

    `ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initmxDateTime)`

I followed the instructions but I keep seeing the same error.

Also, I when I tried to follow the instructions above the step 1 goes well, but when executing the second one I get


    `/usr/bin/python: No module named _pylibmc; 'pylibmc' is a package and cannot be directly executed`


Any idea?

Can the error be with initmxDateTime?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Jordan! It sounds like you don't have the same problem at all. The `ImportError` you pasted is about `mxDateTime`. The root cause is the same (missing symbol in shared object) but entirely different packages for entirely different reasons. Try rebuilding `mxDateTime`, can you import pylibmc?